# Can I generate a pass for Passbook without using a server?

Tags: ios, ios6, passbook

According to Passbook Programming Guide, I need a server to create a Pass for Passbook.
Is there a way to generate .pkpass for Passbook locally in the iOS device without involving a server? If there's a way to do this, is this allowed by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no. Is not allowed and you lose most of the features of the Passbook system.

There are also many security issues like the need to embed the certificate in the app and distribute it to everyone (so anyone can generate passes without your permission).

Any pass needs to be issued by an authority and on a computer, not on the device itself.

You can actually generate a pass on a computer not connected to the internet, but the pass will be orphaned and cannot be updated.